# PHP files downloading when using php-fpm and nginx with Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I already saw other posts here about a similar issue, but I think mine needs a different solution because the other posts didn't help.

I am running two separate containers with Docker: For `php-fpm` and for `nginx`.
When I try to display text using `index.html` file it's all ok, but when I change the file name to `index.php` it downloads a "download" file instead.

I'm not sure if it's only because of my `default.conf` file or because of how I setup my containers.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
    laravel:


services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "8088:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html 
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
            
        networks:
            - laravel
        
    
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql

        tty: true
        ports:
            - "4306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql            
        
        networks:
            - laravel
          
    
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel
```

This is my `default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the main part: the `fastcgi_pass` directive to actually forward the request to FPM. Add this under the `location ~ \.php$`  section:

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

See also [the example in Nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Comment: Thank you! it worked